# How can I tell Mercer Frey to kindly buzz off?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At a point in the Thieve's Guild questline, Mercer Frey accompanies you to a dungeon. He has no dialogue other than one unimportant option, so you cannot ask him to stop following you. After several tries, I decided that the dungeon included in the quest is too hard to clear, so I'd like to level up before continuing. However, since Mercer won't stop following me, he continues to screw up my play style (as a sneak Illusion-type character), alerting people of my presence by opening doors that I've closed, standing in line-of-sight, etc.

He's very annoying. Without the aid of a mod, is there a console command or other way to tell him to buzz off while not breaking the quest when I chose to return to it?

Comment: How can second hand of thieves guild be so bad at sneaking xD ... Actually  that would explain why they lost all the former glory in the first place.

Comment: id recommend just lowering the difficulty and finishing the dungeon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are on the "[Speaking With Silence](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speaking_With_Silence)" quest.If it is the quest ID will be TG05 if not you can simply find your quest on the UESP and use its ID number.

---

You can reset the quest to it's initial stage ("meet Mercer Frey outside Snow Veil Sanctum") using

```
   setstage <quest id> <stage value>
```

in your case

```
   setstage TG05 0
```

or

```
   resetquest TG05
```

This will reset your progress,quest items and followers linked to this quest/dungeon.

---

<strike>Use</strike>

```
  prid 00022651
```

to select Mercer,then

```
  setunconscious 1
```

to turn off his AI,he should just vegetate in the place you left him until you turn on his brain with

```
  setunconscious 0
```

Haven't tested this so I'm not sure what can go wrong.

As it turns out Mercer Frey will still teleport to your location(in attempt to follow you) if you go too far,however might be used in different scenario.

---

You can also try with **set playerfollowercount to 0**.Or using **Disable** then **Enable** on him,similar with **Kill** and **Revive**...But try them only as last resort since there is so much things that can go wrong with this commands(in regards to your quest).

Comment: I've tried using `setstage`, but it did not appear to do anything. I've managed to stick Mercer in a safe place using the `setunconscious` command, we'll see what happens when I unfreeze him!

Comment: I had to unaccept this answer.. After playing a while with Mercer unconscious, I was sneaking around in a house and found him running in place.. on his back.. in the house.

Comment: Lool for the bug,I guess he tried to follow you without his brain(make note,bad idea).

But setstage should work,I have a lot of mods in Skyrim which brings a lot of bugs and I used this command to control my quests at least 15 times,it started to be very important feature for bugged quests.

Go on the link I provided and check the bottom of the article for quest stages and codes,also check here http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console for more info about the setstage.Try setting it to stage 0 or 1...or you could try ending the quest with 200 and see if you can then re-enable it with 10 or 0

Comment: I'm not sure if it was `stopquest` or `resetquest`, but one of those managed to end the entire quest, therefor stopping Mercer. I assume I can just use `setstage` to resume when I'm ready. If you edit your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Oh,It was "resetquest",and now I see why the "setstage 10" didn't work."resetquest" is equivalent to "setstage 0" which puts the initial quest in your journal.And "setstage 10" is "setstage 0" but completed.So when you entered the number 10 it was putting you on the same part of the quest you were already on,and you couldn't see the change.